# Is this correct way to implement task-based asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to add big number of item's to listbox
first I define a delegate which hold a reference to anonymous method that add the specific 
item object to the listbox Items Collection

```
delegate void D();
```

then I write the asynchronous method as well

```
private async void AddAsync()
{

        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
                {
                    D r = new D(() => this.listBox1.Items.Add(i));
                    this.listBox1.Invoke(r);
                }
            }
            );
}
```

is this correct way to Implement a TAP ?
do I made a mistake ? 
and from performance perspective can you suggest a better logic ? or this is good enough

Comment: A listbox with 40,000 items? I am not sure that is going to fly but if you insist I believe it would be better to create one task that adds 40,000 items to the listbox instead of creating 40,000 tasks that each add a single item to the listbox.

Comment: oh, I made a big mistake, I have edit the method thank you

Comment: From a performance point of view, this is possibly the worst thing you can do. As Martin said, since you're updating UI which has to be done on the UI thread, it's much more efficient doing this in a single threaded loop on the UI thread. In a UI environment, in general, you want to shift long running ** non UI related ** tasks to background and only invoke them on the UI thread when the results of these long running operations are available but when updating UI like this, you're better off doing it in the main thread instead of creating 40,000 tasks to do it.

Comment: I've edited the method to run the whole loop inside single background thread <single task> is this better now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the entire point of background threads is to do *background work*. In your example, there is no background work; the entire background delegate is just sending work to the UI thread.

If this is actually representative of your code, you may as well just do it on the UI thread directly:

```
private void Add()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
    this.listBox1.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Note that *adding* the items to the UI is a *UI operation*, so it *must* be done on the UI thread. Now, if *creating* the items takes some time, then you can benefit from background work:

```
private async Task AddAsync()
{
  IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(x => this.listBox1.Items.Add(x));
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
    {
      int value = i; // TODO: replace this with the long-running create-item code.
      progress.Report(value);
    }
  });
}
```

Note the use of `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` to avoid the outdated `Control.Invoke` mechanism.

Comment: thank you , I was think if I use background thread then the UI thread will not do any work , sorry for this misunderstanding, can you please explain why it useful to use background thread for the operations that takes time, cause in any case the UI thread will receive request for updating it's controls ? I test the code it's really different from relying on the UI thread

Comment: @MadMass: Background threads are useful for doing *non-UI work* on another thread. So if it takes a second or so to create each item, that work can be done by a background thread, and the UI thread only has to spend the 10ms or so that it takes to add the item.